# Gearman Submit Multiple Jobs AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-2.7, gearman, python-gearman

What I'm trying to achieve here is to submit **multiple jobs** to Gearman and **print the results returned** by the workers once they are done with processing the job.

I've read through the examples on:

https://pythonhosted.org/gearman/1to2.html#client-multiple-tasks 
https://pythonhosted.org/gearman/client.html

I then tried to implement the check_request_status in the following way:

```
list_of_jobs = []

for i in xrange(1,4,1):
    list_of_jobs.extend(dict(task='run_task', data=str(i)))

completed_requests = gm_client.wait_until_jobs_completed(submitted_requests,
                                                              poll_timeout=30.0)

for job_request in completed_requests:
    if job_request.complete:
        print job_request.result
    elif job_request.timed_out:
        print "Job %s timed out!" % job_request.unique
    elif job_request.state == JOB_UNKNOWN:
        print "Job %s connection failed!" % job_request.unique
```

I'm getting the following error which I can't seem to figure out even after much Google-fu, searching through the Gearman Google Groups and poring through other people's implementation of Gearman:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supervisor.py", line 16, in <module>
    completed_requests = gm_client.submit_multiple_jobs(list_of_jobs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gearman/client.py", line 48, in submit_multiple_jobs
    requests_to_submit = [self._create_request_from_dictionary(job_info, background=background, max_retries=max_retries) for job_info in jobs_to_submit]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gearman/client.py", line 169, in _create_request_from_dictionary
    job_unique = job_info.get('unique')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error is a simple one. In the for-loop above, simply use the append function instead of extend for adding a dict to the list_of_jobs array:

```
list_of_jobs.append(dict(task='run_task', data=str(i)))
```